How to remove the small space between the top tabs bar and the first line of the code area in Sublime Text?
I am trying to remove the small space between the top tabs bar and the first line of the code area in Sublime Text 4 but have no luck so far. I also took help of chatGPT but it couldn't.
Here is the screenshot to help you understand what I am talking about (tiny white space between tab bar and blue highlighted line):

What settings I need to add in theme or color scheme file? I'm using Default theme and my custom color scheme.
